# Image in Button does not update (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

I'm developing an app for iOS (still learning) and I have a button that works sort of like a combo box: when clicked it opens a new scene with a table view, displaying the elements that when clicked returns to the previous scene and calls the *updatePartner:* method. And up until this point it works just fine. But when I try to update the image of the button it just doesn't update it...

```
- (void) updatePartner:(NSInteger)index
{
NSLog(@"updatePartner: %i", index);

NSString *partnerImage = @"";
UIImage *image = @"";
NSString *text = @"";

switch (index)
{
    case 0:
        partnerImage = @"ic_pcmedic_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 1:
        partnerImage = @"ic_sapo_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 2:
        partnerImage = @"ic_telepac_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 3:
        partnerImage = @"ic_meo_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 4:
        partnerImage = @"ic_zon_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 5:
        partnerImage = @"ic_caboviaso_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 6:
        partnerImage = @"ic_artelecom_h45.png";
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:partnerImage];
        break;

    case 7:
        text = @"Ainda não sou cliente";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if (index <= 6)
    [[self partnerButton] setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [[self partnerButton] setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[self partnerButton] setNeedsDisplay];
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Any help would be apreciated!

UPDATE: I have been around with this but still haven't figured it out.... I have tested the method inside the *viewDidLoad:* method of the same class of *updatePartner:* and it works, it's when I call it from another class that it doesn't work... PLEASE HELP!!! Thank you!

Regards,
Ricardo Amendoeira

Comment: Did you add these image to the project? And images are belong to correct target?

Comment: yes. and I know that images work in the project because I put images on the table view programmatically (not the same images).

Comment: And it doesn't work for the text either (case 7).

Comment: Is partnerButton hooked up correctly in the nib? (verify it is not nil at runtime)

Comment: I observed that partnerButton isn't null on _viewDidLoad_, but it is on _updatePartner:_. I have no clue why this is happening...

Comment: Is this button created in code or in a xib or storyboard? What kind of reference do you have for it (a property?) and how is that declared?

Comment: Maybe always index > 6 ?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t set your initial empty image to `@""`. This is the empty string. You should instead do `UIImage *image;`, or perhaps `UIImage *image = nil;` if you’re not sure your image will be initialized.

Comment: You say it's null in updatePartner:,Can you please check the scope of the button? Is it declared on the view level?

Comment: NeverBe: No, the index is going fine.
Zev: did that, but it didn't hange anything...
ilight: What do you mean? (sorry I'm a noob :S)

Comment: UPDATE: I have been around with this but still haven't figured it out.... I have tested the method inside the _viewDidLoad:_ method of the same class of _updatePartner:_ and it works, it's when I call it from another class that it doesn't work... PLEASE HELP!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did u made IBOutlets for the Images in the .h file?

then u can make this:

```
yourimagesetoutlet.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imagename.png"];
```

try to use this!! this will probably solve your problem

make something like

```
switch (index)
{
    case 0:
        yourimagesetoutlet.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imagename.png"];

        break;
}
```

Comment: You mean make an outlet for each image? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
if (index <= 6) {
    [[self partnerButton] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [[self partnerButton] setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: That´s not exactly what I want, what I want is the image in top of the white button background. But thanks!! ;)